# How to make Material-UI GridListTitleBar and Image a Link in ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI GridList to display a list of Events in React. Everything is working fine except that I am not able to make Title or Image a Link. Does anyone know how to make Title and Image a Link?

Here is my Component.

```
<div className={classes.root}>
  <GridListTile key="Subheader" style={{ height: "auto" }}>
    <ListSubheader component="div">This is List of Events</ListSubheader>
  </GridListTile>
  <GridList
    cellHeight={330}
    cols={matches ? 1 : 3}
    className={classes.gridList}
    spacing={12}
  >
    {tileData.length > 0 &&
      tileData.map((tile, index) => {
        return (
          <GridListTile
            key={Math.floor(Math.random() * new Date().getTime())}
          >
            <img src={tile.eventImage} alt={tile.title} />
            <GridListTileBar
              title={tile.title}
              subtitle={<span>by: {tile.description}</span>}
              actionIcon={<IconButton title={tile.title} />}
            />
          </GridListTile>
        );
      })}
  </GridList>
</div>
);
```

### Update

This is an update to the answer that was given below. The first image is now smaller than the rest of the images after update the code with the solution given below.

[image: The first image is now smaller than the rest of the images]

Here is the new code that I am trying:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
  <GridListTile key="Subheader" style={{ height: "auto" }}>
    <ListSubheader component="div">This is List of Events</ListSubheader>
  </GridListTile>
  <GridList
    cellHeight={330}
    cols={matches ? 1 : 3}
    className={classes.gridList}
    spacing={12}
  >
    {tileData.length > 0 &&
      tileData.map((tile, index) => {
        return (
          <GridListTile
            key={Math.floor(Math.random() * new Date().getTime())}
          >
            <a href={"events/" + tile._id + "/eventcomments"}>
              <img
                src={tile.eventImage}
                alt={tile.title}
                className="MuiGridListTile-imgFullHeight"
              />
              <GridListTileBar title={tile.title} />
            </a>
          </GridListTile>
        );
      })}
  </GridList>
</div>
```

Comment: Feedback: this question was edited into a confusing state, and I have tried to repair it. When an answer is given to a question, the question should not be rewritten based on that answer e.g. because the problem has changed. This is because, for readers in the future, the answer given will no longer make sense based on the question as it now stands.

Comment: I have therefore rolled the question back to the last good state, and then added the new version of the code in an update section. This makes it much clearer to readers what the original problem was, and how it evolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to get it to work without breaking or stretching my images, and here is what I did.

```
<div className={classes.root}>
  <GridListTile key="Subheader" style={{ height: "auto" }}>
    <ListSubheader component="div">This is List of Events</ListSubheader>
  </GridListTile>
  <GridList
    cellHeight={330}
    cols={matches ? 1 : 3}
    className={classes.gridList}
    spacing={12}
  >
    {tileData.length > 0 &&
      tileData.map((tile, index) => {
        return (
          <GridListTile
            component={Link}
            to={"/events/" + tile._id + "/eventcomments"}
            key={Math.floor(Math.random() * new Date().getTime())}
          >
            <img src={tile.eventImage} alt={tile.title} />
            <GridListTileBar title={tile.title} />
          </GridListTile>
        );
      })}
  </GridList>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the image with an anchor tag like this:

```
// ...
<GridListTile key={Math.floor(Math.random() * new Date().getTime())}>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/">
    <img src={tile.eventImage} alt={tile.title} className="MuiGridListTile-imgFullHeight" />
  </a>
  <GridListTileBar
    title={tile.title}
    subtitle={<span>by: {tile.description}</span>}
    actionIcon={<IconButton title={tile.title} />}
  />
</GridListTile>
// ...
```

---

It is important, after wrapping the image inside an anchor tag to add the class `MuiGridListTile-imgFullHeight` to the image to keep the same styling of the grid. Normally this class is added automatically, but if you wrap it inside an anchor tag it isn't. So you need to add it manually.

**Update**

The image shows expected behavior, because your first image is not wide enough to cover the whole tile and you only added the class to scale the img to full height. There is also a class to scale to full width: `MuiGridListTile-imgFullWidth`, but you can't use both of these classes together for your use case as the styles conflict (see the style definition here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/GridListTile/GridListTile.js).

You can try to set the width to `100%` in the image style prop:

```
<img
  // ...
  style={{ width: "100%" }}
  className="MuiGridListTile-imgFullHeight"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Bas but the only problem that I am facing now is that the size of the first Event on the list is now smaller than the rest of the Events.

Comment: Did you add the class to the image like I did in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I did. @Bas  I have updated my question with the result I am getting.

Comment: I just did now @Bas can you check it now

Comment: Than you so much @Bas, I like the fact that you explained everything that you did and the reason for the problem. Everything is now working properly as it should except that the images are being stretched/squeezed. Thanks again.

Comment: Is it possible to use <Link to={}> to make a link, as you would do in the normal React app? just to avoid the breaking of the image, the solution you gave me works fine except that it squeezes the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Gallery = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Fragment>
    <div style={{background: "black"}}>
    <Toolbar/>
    <Grid container spacing={0}>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>GALERIA</Paper>
    <div className={classes.root}>
    <GridList cellHeight={280} className={classes.gridList} cols={1}>
        {tileData.map((tile) => (
          <GridListTile style={{ width: "100%" }}  key={tile.img} cols={tile.cols || 1}>
            <img  src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} />
          </GridListTile>
        ))}
    </GridList>
    </div>
    </Grid>
    </Grid>
    </div>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
export default Gallery;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type of underlying component rendered by the GridListTime Material-UI component. Just add the `component="a"` to have it render as an anchor tag. Then you may specify an `href` prop to pass in your route. See below:

```
<GridList cellHeight={160} className={classes.gridList} cols={3}>
  {tileData.map((tile) => (
    <GridListTile key={tile.img} cols={tile.cols || 1} component="a" href="/">
      <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} />
    </GridListTile>
  ))}
</GridList>
```